# What is the name of the song in episode 19 at roughly 12 minutes?

Tags: music, welcome-to-the-ballroom

In episode 19, at roughly 12 minutes, there's a song playing. I looked through the OST album and couldn't find it.

What is the name of the song, and where could I possibly find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the OST that starts playing while we see [a shot of schoolchildren at the swimming pool](https://youtu.be/ksrntf-O-_Y?t=754), it's まったりとした日常 (*Mattari to Shita Nichijou*), which you can listen to a preview of on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/welcome-to-the-ballroom-original-soundtrack/1316413910).